# In ChromeDevTools, how do I stop/halt the page when it's reaching an endless JavaScript loop error?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a webpage which is created based on jQuery and jQuery UI.

As jQuery-UI is too big, I'd like to remove it and write my own easing functions.

However, after removing the jQuery UI, I got an endless error in my ChromeDevTool:

[image]

Though I know how to fix the bug, is there any way that I could halt the page in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: This is essentially asking to solve the halting problem for which there's no general solution.

Comment: I thought that Chrome DevTools might have a "STOP" button/feature to halt the page.

Comment: There's a pause button in the Sources panel but devtools itself may be locked by the page.